Would two switches in parallel in the same box meet code?
For convenience, I'd like my workshop light to be controllable by the home automation.
For safety, I'd like to be able to bypass that and force the lights to stay on when unexpected sudden darkness might be dangerous.
Can I get away with just putting a normal switch in parallel to bypass the Smart switch? Or should I think about installing separate area lighting and safety lighting?
In theory it's no weirder than a three-way circuit... But I suspect that it's uncommon.
(Most good quality smart switches do have a mechanical switch designed into them to force the circuit to stay off, for those who are worried about someone turning it on while they are changing light bulbs or similar. Haven't seen one with a bypass.)

By unexpected sudden darkness, Can I assume you mean the smart switches failing, instead of power going out?  Sometimes simple dumb circuits are handy.  Having a LED flashlight handy is a second idea.

@crip659: Scenario: lights go out, table saw continues running. I would rather reduce the risk of that happening, not try to deal with it once it has, even with preparation. I can't reduce the risk to zero, but in this environment I am not going to put the smart switch in at all unless I can preserve the physical switch. It's a specific solution for a specific scenario; might not be of any interest to anyone else... But I wanted to know whether there was anything in code which said I couldn't do it. (At least one tupo foxed. I hate the 5-min editing limit on comments...)

I would just add a light to the saw and wire it so that it turns on when it's running. Same scenario can happen when when a breaker pops or when you lose one phase, and bypass switch won't help.

Yes, this is legal - the NEC does not prohibit it.
The NEC does prohibit two "paralleling" situations, neither of which is applicable here:

Code prohibits having the current-carrying conductors of a circuit being in different cables or different conduits. This is because having the conductors of an AC circuit spaced physically far apart can lead to vibrations (which can lead to loosening connections, and then arcing/fire) and induction of currents into nearby wires and metals, which can shock people. This does not apply here. Having two parallel switches in one box is no worse than pushing the two wires of a circuit to opposite sides of a large box that they pass through.

Code prohibits paralleling conductors to achieve a higher ampacity rating, below a certain circuit size and without using specially listed equipment (e.g. you can't wire-nut two #14 wires together for a 30A circuit). Even less relevant here.



I think the key is to understand the concern about "paralleling". It isn't about having two switches control one thing. It is a concern about having balanced loads, which generally depends on having either hot + switched hot or hot + neutral for a given load in the same cable or conduit.
This means, for example, that if hot and neutral come from the panel and split in one box to two separate cables going to separate switches would be a problem as the electrons don't know which neutral to use (so to speak).
On the other hand, if the two switches are in one box then hot and neutral come into the box and hot and recombined switched hot go out of the box and everything is OK.
There is even another possibility: Hot/neutral go into the fixture. A switch loop (new, so hot + switched hot + neutral) goes down to each switch. Since the neutral in that situation is only to power the smart switch itself (and the other switch will have neutral capped), the currents in each cable will be balanced.
All that being said (i.e., should be easy to do this in a code compliant and reliable manner), from a pure life-safety standpoint this isn't a good idea. Why? Because unless you use a lockout on the manual switch, you could a situation with multiple people working at different times on different things (some safety-critical, some not) and you end up with someone remotely turning off the "App" switch while someone else is working who thought the manual switch was on but it wasn't because someone else turned it off earlier.
So a better way to handle this is to have two separate light circuits. The primary one can be smart, possibly with manual override as well. The secondary one would either always be on (yes, wastes energy) or perhaps always on with a master switch - i.e., so nobody can use any power equipment at all without at least the minimal safety lighting on.

OP hasn't told us why he wants this, but I think if we give him some benefit of the doubt, it must be that flashlights do not solve his problem and the backup switch is indeed in the same room or box, not in some other place causing occupational danger.   Let's try to be generous.  My guess is he has purchased some PoS smart gear, or he has an unreliable WiFi network, or both, and certain people who shall remain nameless are becoming fed up with it all.  :) :) :)   (It's a safe bet that everyone on this site is in that boat.)

No, it's that I am a programmer and do not want to trust that there is no way that system could glitch and turn off the lights, whether it be a server error, a hub error, or a user error elsewhere in the house. No matter how good the system, those risks  do exist in a home automation setup. I can't protect against somebody pulling the circuit breaker, but I can protect against misuse or malfunction. Perhaps I should put in emergency lights too, but one issue at a time and this should be easy unless code says no. (Typos partly from trying to use dictation with radio in background; sorry.)

And yes, the smart switch and backup switch would both be in the workshop. Before working there I would throw the hard switch; when just passing through or entering from the other door I could take advantage of the smart switch in lieu of three-way wiring.

The intent is to have the switches wired literally in parallel in a single box.

Yes, running a second light circuit not controlled by the home automation would be an alternative. But if I do that, I might as well just put in a loop for three-way and not bother with the automation at all;. Perfectly reasonable solution, but it doesn't answer my question of whether two switches in parallel would ever be permitted

Usually with "just in case" questions I like to have a better description of the failures that might occur and the need for mitigation.  What you're asking for, shouldn't be necessary.  But sometimes it is and I think I can take a stab and hopefully be close to what you want.
If you want to be able to bypass the "smart" features and force a light on:

You must use traditional bulbs, not smart ones, and control them with smart switches.  I may be wrong, as I have only seen a tiny percentage of what exists, but I don't know of any smart bulbs that allow you to easily bypass their smart state and "just turn on", without doing a factory-reset (not what you want).
The smart switches in turn will be "smart" on the app side, ie, you can control them with apps.  But on the power side they will act as ordinary switches, turning power on and off.
Then, yes you can put an ordinary switch in parallel and it will force the light on, bypassing the smart switch's "off" state.

The harm you will do is to confuse anyone who doesn't know what the two switches are for.  You can fix that with labels.
I'll take a wild swing at guessing why you want to do this -- I may be way off -- but if you want reliable smart switching of essential home lighting (ie, all room lighting, as opposed to accent lighting, exterior uplighting, etc) -- reliable -- you should stick to ZWave and Zigbee for the time being, you should sit around and wait for the thousands of cloud-based products currently available to become obsolete, which will happen soon, and switch to Matter over Thread when that becomes mature.   Not yet.  When it's fully baked, it will be almost as reliable as dumb lighting and far more reliable than all the smart stuff we now have riding cloud services.

I would indeed be using a smart switch, not smart bulbs. For my purposes, smart bulbs are only useful when color change is needed, or when it is impossible to use a smart switch/dimmer.

Having a dumb switch parallel to a smart switch is not a breach of code. No matter the level of smartness, they are just switches. Your approach is just adding redundancy to the system - one switch fails, the other still do the job.
On the other hand, your comment states

lights go out, table saw continues running. I would rather reduce the risk of that happening.

In that case I would install relay in sequence with the lights. If the lights go off, the relay switches the emergency lights on.
If you want to go fail-safe, power up the emergency lights from UPS. (Can be 12V LED lights and 12V car battery)

Or just buy a standard emergency light unit and wire it into the lighting circuit ahead of the switches, which is what you are suggesting recreating.

Yes, buy it or DIY.
